# MySQL update columns from table 1 based on columns on column 2 - very slow (have indexed)

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 2 tables. a 'property' table and a 'postcodelatlng' table.

In postcodelatlng I have postcode, latitude and longitude columns. There is only 1 postcode per latitude and longitude.

In property I also have postcode, latitude and longitude columns. There are multiple properties with the same postcode.

I want all of my current blank latitude and longitude values in property to be updated with the correct latitude and longitude values from postcodelatlng.

Below is what I'm currently using, but it's taking a long time. I expect it to take some time (22 million rows in property, 1.7 million in postcodelatlng)... but even after 5 minutes, I don't see ANY new latitude/longitude values in property table.

I have indexed property (postcode, latitude, longitude) and the same for postcodelatlng.

```
UPDATE `property` 
INNER JOIN `postcodelatlng` on `property`.`postcode` = `postcodelatlng`.`postcode`
SET `property`.`latitude` = `postcodelatlng`.`latitude`, `property`.`longitude` = `postcodelatlng`.`longitude`
```

Comment: Do you update all in one run? The better approach is to divide your table in chunks and commit for example every 1000/10000 rows.

Comment: It's my first time dealing with such large tables. Is this a query capability, or do I need to change the structure of the database?

Comment: You just add where condition based on "driving" table and do something like `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 1000` and so on

Comment: Ah right yes. Didn't think of that route. Works a treat, many thanks

Comment: Maybe it's getting a memory overflow dealing with this huge transaction